# C# lambda expressions as array extensions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a lot of lambda expressions in C#, so I've decided to create some similar functionality in JavaScript. Since jQuery is included in my projects, I'm using [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) instead of [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to support older browsers without including shims.

The two examples below corresponds to [Where()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb910018(v=vs.90).aspx) and [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909042(v=vs.90).aspx) in C#:

```
if(!Array.prototype.where){

    Array.prototype.where = function (func) {

        var that = this;

        switch (typeof func) { 

            case 'function': 
                return $.grep(that, func); 

            case 'object':

                for(var prop in func){
                    that = $.grep(that, function(item){
                        return item[prop] === func[prop];
                    });
                }

                return that;

            default: 
                throw new ReferenceError("no/wrong func type passed"); 
        }
    };
}

if(!Array.prototype.firstOrDefault){

    Array.prototype.firstOrDefault = function(func){
        return this.where(func)[0] || null;
    };
}
```

```
var persons = [{ name: 'foo', age: 1 }, { name: 'bar', age: 2 }];

var where1 = persons.where(function(p){
    return p.age === 1 && p.name === 'foo';
});

console.log(where1);

var where2 = persons.where({ age: 1, name: 'foo' });

console.log(where2);

var fod1 = persons.firstOrDefault(function(p){
    return p.age === 1 && p.name === 'foo';
});

console.log(fod1);

var fod2 = persons.firstOrDefault({ age: 1, name: 'foo' });

console.log(fod2);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzrhj5rg/)

I would have preferred to add the methods as non-enumerable using `Object.defineProperty`, but since I need to support IE >= 7, that's not an option.

However, the only downside with having the methods enumerable would be if someone is iterating an array using `for..in`, which they shouldn't do in the fist place.

In case of an `object` being passed as argument, one way to decrease the total iterations from array length * object property count to array length * 1 could be solved using the function constructor:

```
var o = { foo: 1, bar: true, s: 's' };

var str = Object.keys(o).reduce(function (prev, key) {

    if(typeof o[key] === 'string')
        o[key] = '\'' + o[key] + '\'';
    return (prev ? prev + ' && ' : '') + 'x.' + key + ' === ' + o[key];

}, '');

var f = new Function('x', 'return ' + str + ';');

// pass f to filter/$.grep
console.log(f);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/abbj48u8/)

I would like some feedback about possible performance improvements and what you think about the code in general (but not pros and cons with extending native objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks OK to me. I don't know that you could do anything to really squeeze more performance out of this. In the end you're mostly dependent on how `$.grep` performs.

I set up [a jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/3-kinds-of-grepping) for your own alternatives and the code below, and constructing a function is *by far* the fastest (I put the function construction into `where`, and avoided using `reduce` since you said you'd need IE7+ support).

**But!** Constructing a function from text is just tremendously fragile:

- Quoting a string is a pain. If the string contains single or double quotes, you can't properly quote it without *a lot* of parsing and escaping. You just really shouldn't try.
- Your `'x.' + prop` accessing can easily fail too, if the key isn't a proper "word". Any string can be a property name, including strings with spaces, reserved words, operators, etc.. You end up with code like `x.hey look a string key === ....`, which won't get you very far.
  Using subscripting access, i.e. `'x["' + prop + '"]'`, will get you a bit further, but you're just back to the issue of quoting strings again.
- Only primitive values can be easily compared; you'd still need a custom function for everything else.
- You're changing the object that's been passed in; specifically, string values get quoted. I assume that's partly just because it's an example, but still. (I avoided this in the jsperf code.)

So yeah, it's much faster to use a function, but I'd still very much avoid constructing one on the fly. Better to just write one when necessary, or accept the performance hit otherwise.

As for the existing code, I like the iterative way of reducing the matches if the argument is an object. But I wanted to try turning the loops inside out, as I find that more straightforward:

```
return $.grep(this, function (item) {
  for(var prop in func) {
    if(item[prop] !== func[prop]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

However, doing so is *slower* (somewhat to my surprise).

Otherwise, the code's fine, I only have a couple of notes.

- The `that` variable would usually imply that you're dealing with scopes, but that isn't the case here; You can use plain `this` anywhere in your function. You do need a separate variable for the object-based filtering, but I'd just do something like `var filtered = this`.
- You should throw a `TypeError` instead of a `ReferenceError`. And I'd write a slightly nicer and more helpful error message, such as "func must be either a function or an object of properties and values to filter by".
- You'll probably want to add a `func.hasOwnProperty(prop)` check to avoid accidentally looping through a bunch of inherited properties. It's not an issue for object literals, but it can be for other objects.
- You'll probably want to ensure that a copy of the original array in returned, even if nothing's been filtered. This isn't a problem if you pass in a function, but could happen if you pass in an empty object.
- It's a tad heavy on the whitespace, if you ask me, but to each their own.

In the end, I get this

```
Array.prototype.where = function (filter) {
    switch(typeof filter) { 
        case 'function': 
            return $.grep(that, filter); 

        case 'object':
            var filtered = this;
            for(var prop in filter) {
              if(!filter.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                  continue; // ignore inherited properties
              }
              filtered = $.grep(filtered, function (item) {
                  return item[prop] === filter[prop];
              });
            }
            return filtered.slice(0); // copy the array

        default: 
            throw new TypeError("func must be either a function or an object of properties and values to filter by"); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's better to take a performance hit than dealing with all the issues related to constructing the function from a string. Could you please elaborate the part about returning a new copy of the array? Could you show me a fiddle where it could become an issue not to copy it? Both `$.grep` and `filter` would return a new array AFAIK. Thanks for your input, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Johan [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/L45boes8/). The point is just that your function always returns a new array **except** if you pass an empty object as your filter (because in that case, you never call `$.grep`). In that single edge case, you just get the original array reference back, and any modifications you make will affect the original array. Could be a really nasty bug to track down later.